# Discord BOT check for a message containing certain text

Tags: c#, visual-studio, discord, discord.net

I'm trying to make it so it'll send a message if that channel has any message with that users name saying "@BLAH 1/3 Foul Language" that'll check then send a new message saying "@BLAH 2/3 Foul Language"

```
if (warningsChannel.Messages.ToString().Contains(e.User.Mention + " 1/3 foul language")) {
                    await warningsChannel.SendMessage(e.User.Mention + " 2/3 foul language");
                } else if(warningsChannel.Messages.ToString().Contains(e.User.Mention + " 2/3 foul language")){
                    await warningsChannel.SendMessage(e.User.Mention + " 3/3 foul language");
                } else if (warningsChannel.Messages.ToString().Contains(e.User.Mention + " 3/3 foul language")){
                   await warningsChannel.SendMessage(e.User.Mention + " has been kicked from our server for foul language.");
                    await e.User.Kick();
                }else if(warningsChannel.Messages.ToString().Contains("")){
                    await warningsChannel.SendMessage(e.User.Mention + " 1/3 foul language");
                }
```

Comment: What discord.net version are you using? Elaborate more in what you are trying to do.

Comment: Latest version & what I'm trying to get it to do is look for a message containing the user's name with that following warning message. If it finds it, it'll either ban if it's their last warning or give them another warning.

Answer (score 1):

Use await warningsChannel.DownloadMessages(amount);

Be careful not to download over 100 messages though.